# Split the string and compare in Python

Tags: python, string

I am getting the output of type(str) in Linux prompt as below:-

```
[ INFO ]     : 2020-05-21 05:06:46.079000    : 06:37:644777] cal_status = "Connected"
```

I want validation like:

```
if  cal_status == "Connected"
    validation successful
else:
    validation fail
```

I trying through `split("]")` and in for loop again I split through == but I am getting an error

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: splitsring=command_output.split("]")
print(splitsring)
for i in splitsring:
               
                valuearr=i.strip().split("=")
                 if(valuearr[0].strip()=="cal_status") : 
                    if(valuearr[1].strip() is "CONNECTED"):
                        print("Validation successfull of params  ")
                        print(valuearr[1])
                    else:
                        print("\nValidation Failed for params")
                        print(valuearr[1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are going line by line through the output, or you already have the single target line to check, you could use `re.search` here:

```
inp = '[ INFO ]     : 2020-05-21 05:06:46.079000    : 06:37:644777] cal_status = "Connected"'
if re.search(r'\bcal_status = "Connected"', inp):
    print("MATCH")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try doing:

```py
str = '[ INFO ]     : 2020-05-21 05:06:46.079000    : 06:37:644777] cal_status = "Connected"'
if a.split("cal_status = ")[-1] == '"Connected"':
    print('Validation Successful')
else:
    print('Validation Fail')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that string `cal_status = "Connected"` will always come like this then you can also do this

```
str = '[ INFO ]     : 2020-05-21 05:06:46.079000    : 06:37:644777] cal_status = "Connected"'
arr = str.split(" ")
for index, item in enumerate(arr):
    if item == "cal_status":
        if arr[index + 2].lower() == '"connected"':
            print('Validation Successful')
            exit()
        else:
            print('Validation Fail')
```

Need to add checks for array index validation